# Get last entry for each user in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL table `user_login` with two columns, `userId` and `tstamp`. Each entry contains the userId of the user who logged in, as well as the associated timestamp. If a user logged in 6 times, then there are six entries associated with the user.

It's easy to obtain a list of users who logged in after a certain date, e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId FROM user_login WHERE tstamp > '2017-10-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY userId HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

How can I generate a table with two columns: `userId` and `lastLoginDate` i.e. the last login date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT userId, MAX(tstamp) AS lastLoginDate
FROM user_login 
WHERE tstamp > '2017-10-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY userId;
```